# RegQueryValueEx, need some assistance

Tags: c++, winapi, registry

Total noob at coding, any advice is appreciated.

This is what I am trying to do:

1) Open the run key in HKLM

2) Read a REG_SZ I have made called "Test".

3) Read the data for "Test"

4) If "this data" found then delete key.

5) Close the key.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>


using namespace std;


int main() {
char value[1024];
DWORD value_length = 1024;
DWORD keytype = REG_SZ;
HKEY hk;
LONG result;
LONG result2;
char response;
cout << "Would you like to scan? (Y) or (N)";
cin >> response;
if (response == 'Y')
{
    result = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &hk);
        if ( result == ERROR_SUCCESS) {

            result2 = RegQueryValueEx(hk, ("Test"), NULL, &keytype, (LPBYTE)&value, &value_length);
            if (result2 == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED) {
                cout << "Access Denied." << endl;
                RegCloseKey(hk);
                system("pause");

            }
            else if (result2 == ERROR_MORE_DATA) {
                cout << "lpData buffer is too small to receive the data." << endl;
                RegCloseKey(hk);
                system("pause");
            }
            else if (result2 == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) {
                cout << "Value does not exist for LpValueName." << endl;
                RegCloseKey(hk);
                system("pause");
            }

            else if (result2 == ERROR_SUCCESS) { //If the function succeeds, the return value is ERROR_SUCCESS.
                cout << "The value read from the registry is: " << value << endl;
                RegCloseKey(hk);
                system("pause");

            }
        }
        else if (result == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
        {
            cout << "Key not found." << endl;
            system("pause");
        }
    }

    else if (response == 'N')
    {
        return 0;
        system("pause");
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try `cout << value << '\n';` to see what it prints?

Comment: What is the problem exactly? You already know how to read the data, you are already doing it. The data is in your `value[]` array. The return value of `RegQueryValueEx()` (which you are ignoring) will tell you if the value exists in the opened key or not, and `value_length` will tell you how many bytes were read. Then you just have to scan the content of `value[]`, such as with `strncmp()`, `strstr()`, etc, depending on your needs. If you find a match, call `RegDeleteValue()`.

Comment: On an unrelated note, `ERROR_SUCCESS` is a misleading name!

Comment: Yeah fixed it, and it does output a value now. However the value is not readable. It outputs   ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠. And yes! I agree.

Comment: You're testing if `RegOpenKeyEx` fails (`!= ERROR_SUCCESS`) which means if it succeeds, you won't read the value from the registry and `value` is uninitialized.

Comment: What @JonathanPotter said, and I indented your code properly so you can see what it's actually doing. You're calling `RegQueryValueEx` **only** when `RegOpenKeyEx` **fails**, and then you're printing the results whether it failed or not.

Comment: Okay, I think I modified it correctly now. It's still not getting the data.

Comment: Guys, as I said, `ERROR_SUCCESS` is misleading (not so unrelated now!). @JesseBropez What does this value actually mean - is it an error (failure condition) or success?

Comment: The read will be a success after the correct value is found, I am trying to use the code to find something bad in the registry and delete it.

Comment: After your latest edit, `ERROR_SUCCESS` is a failure condition! I wonder why people use such confusing names.

Comment: `ERROR_SUCCESS` means... success.

Comment: Even I thought so @JonathanPotter. But it doesn't seem to mean that given the code above!

Comment: The code above is **wrong**. It's testing `if (n == ERROR_SUCCESS)` and returning failure. Look at the code.

Comment: Update your code in the question, don't paste it into a comment. And if it's "failing" explain **how** it's failing.

Comment: So what value does `RegOpenKeyEx` return?

Comment: I got it working now. However, RegQueryValueEx returns a value which is not that of the data in the string "Test". Thank you for your patience everyone, it's helping me learn a lot (very quickly actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic of your check on the value returned by `RegOpenKeyEx` is reversed. Only proceed if `ERROR_SUCCESS` is returned.

```
if (RegOpenKeyEx(...) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    .... // go ahead
```

You aren't checking for errors in the return value of `RegQueryValueEx`. It is probably failing.

It is probably failing because you aren't accounting for the [registry redirector](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232.aspx). You are trying to read from the 64 bit view of the registry but you have a 32 bit process and the redirector means you see the 32 bit view. Pass the [`KEY_WOW64_64KEY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129.aspx) flag to `RegOpenKeyEx` to read from the 64 bit view.

Do beware that strings returned from registry API functions may not be null-terminated. Use the value returned in `value_length` to explicitly add a null-terminator.

When you get the code that reads the key sorted you want to delete it. Because it is under `HKLM` your process will have to run with admin rights. You will have to use an access flag with sufficient rights to delete, that is more powerful that `KEY_READ` in other words.

As an aside, since you chose to use the ANSI API always, the use of the `TEXT` macro is misleading. Personally, I'd opt for the Unicode API.

Comment: Okay, I think I rewrote it correctly. I've been using a lot of tutorials online to figure this out. I do not currently need the 64Key as this isn't in WOW6432Node. It is in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Current Version\Run. The REG_SZ is named "Test". After recompiling, now my program just exits regardless of the option I choose.

Comment: WOW6432Node is the 32 bit view. You need to read from the 64 bit view. Like I said. You need to debug.

Comment: You have to concentrate harder on what I said. Now you ask for KEY_ALL_ACCESS but I bet you don't have admin rights. Anyway, debugging is the skill you are missing. When the functions fail they return error codes. You don't inspect them.

Comment: Thank you for your help David, I think I just might figure this out. Now I am using the specified key, and ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND is being returned when RegOpenKey is called. Also, how do I null terminate it?

Comment: Now your question edit makes my answer invalid. That's not terribly cool. Please stop changing the question. I no longer want to spend my time helping you.

Comment: Alright David, got it all working. I had the key misnamed as "Current Version" instead of CurrentVersion and the result was the key not being found! Thank you to everyone in this thread, all really helped me understand winapi and registry functions. You guys are awesome! Sorry for editing my question, I'm not too familiar with this site, any tips would be great.